# WooCommerce Variable Product Price is not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using variable products on my WooCommerce 2.6.4 shop, I have added different prices for two different variations of the same product. When choosing one of the two variations, no price is displayed at all. The following div is just empty:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation"></div>
```

I would like the pre-selected variation price to be displayed as default, while the non pre-selected variation price should be dynamically replaced when selected. Almost like [this](http://demo.fooevents.com/events/theevent-registration/) demo, except from a pre-selected item and price should be displayed as default.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to your function.php curent theme.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_variation_price', '__return_true' );
```